# Python: DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

ok Im getting this error:DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
 Im trying to plot a csv file and its not working. Any advice? Thank you This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('spacestocksinfo.csv', skipinitialspace=True) 

df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  

for col in df.columns:
    try:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
    except:
        continue


pd.read_csv('spacestocksinfo.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Date',y='High', hue='company')
```

The format of the csv file is this but with many more rows:

```
url,company,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/I/history?p=I,Intelsat S.A.,"Dec 06, 2019",6.10,6.59,6.01,6.53,6.53,"6,737,585"
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/I/history?p=I,Intelsat S.A.,"Dec 05, 2019",6.64,6.68,6.02,6.05,6.05,"5,919,800"
```

Here is the error:

```
File "4.py", line 30, in <module>
    sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Date',y='High', hue='company')
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 1084, in lineplot
    p.plot(ax, kwargs)
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 775, in plot
    x, y, y_ci = self.aggregate(y, x, units)
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 705, in aggregate
    est = grouped.agg(func)
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 845, in aggregate
    return getattr(self, func_or_funcs)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1205, in mean
    "mean", alt=lambda x, axis: Series(x).mean(**kwargs), **kwargs
  File "C:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 888, in _cython_agg_general
    raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

whats going on?

Comment: what version are you running, this works  on 0.25.3 of pandas

Comment: Hmm let me check.... 25.lines its not working when I run the code. Im not getting the lines on the graph.

Comment: Im just getting that error

Comment: what does `df.dtypes` print?

Comment: I found the solution lol

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed a lot of people have had this error. Let me explain the issue. OK so I had to clean the data. One company did not post data for a period of time, that lead to the data being incomplete. I had to delete the parts of the csv that didnt post data. That was causing the error. Once that was dont my code ran. as for the person who said my code was fine, he was right.What I posted here would have worked fine because the part of the csv that I posted here was complete and clean.